# Wordpress meta_query Not Working with 'orderby' - Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**I'm trying to query a custom post type 'section' where the 'section.section_parent_page = {whatever the ID of the current $post is}'.**

This part of the query works fine and is accomplished like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'section',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'section_parent_page', // name of custom relate field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

But once I try to 'orderby' the custom field 'section_position', I either break the query or see no proper ordering. Here's what I currently have:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'section',
    'meta_key' => 'section_position', // custom field I want to order by
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'section_parent_page', // name of custom relate field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

When I look at the $the_query->request, it looks like it continues to order by wp_posts.menu_order

How do I use multiple meta_query arrays to accomplish this?

EDIT:
No matter what I try, the end of my query string ends up looking like this:

```
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: May be this one do the trick [*Sort wp_query by meta value*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261230/sort-wp-query-by-meta-value)

Comment: I tried adding the 'pre_get_posts' filter only to be directed to the 404.php page...

Answer (score 0):

If section_position has integer ( number ) value, use following code

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'section',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
              'meta_key' => 'section_position',
              'order'=>'ASC',
              'meta_query' => array(
                               array(
                                 'key' => 'section_parent_page', // name of custom relate field
                                 'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                                 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                               )
                              ) 
               );
```

Note i have used "meta_value_num" instead of "meta_value"

Comment: I've tried this as well with no luck. Both query strings seem to ignore my 'orderby' clause and still output:ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10

Answer (score -1):

I attempted to do the same thing recently within an ACF filter. I contacted ACF support and received this answer.

> Unfortunately i this query is too complex to be passed through WP_Query and you would have to do a manual SQL query to achieve this.
>   The problem is you are doing two meta_querys, the meta_key = start date and the ones inside the brackets are conflicting.
>   You need the flexibility of full SQL syntax to perform a query like that.