# Wordpress sort custom post type by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query like this:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'proof_gallery',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'meta_key' => '_pixproof_event_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The posts should be displayed by event date, but they get displayed in some random order. As soon as I change orderby to "ID" (and remove the meta_key), it works just fine.

Can anyone see what's wrong? I'm stuck here. It *should* work according to various resources I have found so far.

Comment: Can [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261230/sort-wp-query-by-meta-value) help?

Answer (score 0):

From [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

> meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in
>   the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is
>   fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
>   1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
>   naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values.
>   You may also specify 'meta_type' if you want to cast the meta value as
>   a specific type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR',
>   'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED', same as
>   in '$meta_query'.
>
> 'meta_value_num' - Order by numeric meta value (available since
>   Version 2.8). Also note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present
>   in the query. This value allows for numerical sorting as noted above
>   in 'meta_value'.
>
> > but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
> >     1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
> >     naturally expect).

You should try using `meta_value_num` as your meta seems to be a date

Comment: thanks so far. I have tried both meta_value and meta_value_num.

I found out that the _pixproof_event_date seems to be a string, and thus the posts get sorted in this way:

01.08.2015
01.09.2015

and so on. now I'm not a half decent programmer, so can anyone help me sorting this out?

Comment: Did you try adding ```meta_type``` on your query and set DECIMAL or DATE? Possible ```meta_type``` values are ```'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'```

Comment: Can you explain this any further? I've never heard of WP_Meta_Query. What would I have to do with my query?